# Oil on wood table

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture, table, wood-finishing

in attempts to remove canola oil stains from leaving leaking bottles on the table, I made a solution of water vinegar and baking soda. Unfortunately now, the area I was scrubbing is white from the scrubbing (which I did with a microfiber cloth).

I’m wondering if there are any solutions to this or if I will need to have the table refinished.

The table is a cb2:
[see here](https://www.cb2.com/dylan-36x53-light-acacia-dining-table/f8542)
Thanks for any help!
[image]

Comment: It looks to me like that stripped the finish, it’s possible it is baking soda residue I would try warm water with the microfiber and work it with the grain. Use enough water to dilute any soda. If it looks darker repeat a few times. If the soda an abrasive or the vinegar a week acid or the combination took the surface finish off it will need to be refinished or touched up. I would try several cycles with warm water and see.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It looks like I need to do some refinishing.